# phpmailer external images don't show up

Tags: php, image, email, phpmailer

i'm using phpmailer to send html-templates.
unfortunately external images don't show up on some email clients (e.g. thunderbird)
(no its not the client. not flagged as spam and images enabled. also other mails can display images)

the phpmailer part:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->SetLanguage('de', $path.'email/');
$body = file_get_contents($path.'email/email-template.html');
$replacer = array('{{1}}', '{{2}}', '{{3}}');
$toreplace = array($1, $2, $3);
$body = str_replace($replacer, $toreplace, $body);

$mail->From = 'noreply@host.com';
$mail->FromName = 'noreply@host';
$address = $empfaenger;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $name);
$mail->Subject    = $betreff;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body    = $body;
```

the html-template:

```
...
img src="http://host.com/email/image.png">
...
style="background-image:url(http://host.com/email/image2.png);background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:top left;"
...
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's the format - do JPGs work?

Comment: no :/ png, jpg, or gif wont show up